# How to detect and allow only specific urls to access Flask API, if the call is made in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I've created a flask API as for a website, in which the front-end AJAX calls the API through a POST request on the same domain.

But the API is not protected as anyone can hit a POST request with parameters(which are visible in the JS AJAX) and get a response.

I want to protect this by allowing only certain specific urls to access my Flask API. 
How should I do this in my Python code?

### EXAMPLE

Example Situation - 
Python

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "This is Post"
    return render_template("index.html")
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
url: "https://www.example.com/",
//Something ....
```

So here https://www.example.com/ is the site, the site on which GET request returns the index.html page. But on POST request it return  "This is post". Considering the POST request to be initiated from AJAX, how should I allow only https://www.example.com/ to get the response?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just check for the `request.remote_addr` in the API and return a 404 or whatever other response when the IP doesn't match the one you are expecting?

Comment: If that does not work try `request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']` for getting the client IP.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to require that a page is accessed with a specific client or from a specific location. All information that would indicate that can easily be set to whatever value you look for. For example, if you checked `request.host`, a user can use Python Requests to set the `Host` header:

```
requests.get('http://localhost:5000', headers={'Host': 'example.com'})
```

If you want to restrict *who* can access your API, you need to implement authentication. But that still won't restrict *how* they can access it.

Answer (score -2):

You can check the `request.host_url` in the hook `before_request`:

```
@app.before_request
def check():
    if request.host_url != "http://www.example.com/"
        abort(401)
```

And you can use `Flask-Security` to protect your API. There is a [tutorial](http://mandarvaze.github.io/2015/01/token-auth-with-flask-security.html) about it.